# embed google map in wpf control

Tags: wpf, google-maps

I am trying to create a wpf control that will display a map image using google maps. I want to be able to centre the map on a longitude and latitude specified by the application. Ideally, the control will then allow the user to move a map marker and store the latitude/longitude of the marker in the application.

The only way I can think of doing this is to use a WebBrowser control and create a HTML string at runtime that shows a map of the desired location. This seems like an awkward solution and won't allow me to easily retrieve the marker location. Does anyone know of a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: check http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hosting Google Maps in a Microsoft WPF application using XAML
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/flashmapinwpf.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but I think that doing something like that would violate Google Map's Terms of Service.

Comment: Yes, I have looked into it more closely and it is against the terms. I'm now looking around for an alternative map api that would be suitable.

Comment: Dave are you able to point me to the particular part of the T&C?

Comment: from http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html section 9.1 says it must not be accessible only to an internal network. The app is an internal business app so the api wouldn't be appropriate.

Comment: This sample is from the Google Maps documentation, posted in March 2009 by Marc Ridey, Google Geo Team.
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/flashmapinwpf.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice integration between windows forms and Microsoft Virtual Earth ([sample here](http://mtaulty.com/communityserver/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2005/08/01/5547.aspx).)  There are licensing considerations for commercial products, but this is certainly more or a "turnkey" option.  You would also need to look into the Windows Forms Host to put a Forms control into a WPF app.